# Adding smilies in Custom Keyboard

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I want to add the smilies in the keyboard for text to add the comment  like `:P` and `<3` and if I did so to create the custom keyboard, will Apple reject my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add simple UIView with buttons above the keyboard, and show this view when keyboard appears. By pressing buttons just insert corresponding smiles to text.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using something like UITextField, you can simply create a UIView with buttons like ":P",and assign this view to UITextField's inputAccessoryView property.